# Permuting rows and columns to switch white rooks with black rooks

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, checkerboard, reachability

An adversary places eight white rooks and eight black rooks on sixteen squares of a chessboard, subject to these rules:

- In any row, there must be exactly two rooks, one of each color.
- In any column, there must be exactly two rooks, one of each color.

Your goal is then to apply a number of moves in order to achieve the same configuration, but with the colors reversed. Every valid move consists of switching two rows, or switching two columns.

> Can you always succeed, no matter how the adversary places the pieces?

Click on the pictures to be taken to an online editor where you can play with the rooks.

A possible initial condition:

[image]

The result of switching rows 2 and 4:

[image]

The result of switching columns d and g:

[image]

The goal posiiton:

[image]

Comment: Nice puzzle with a very clever solution! If I may offer a suggestion on the presentation (though there's really no way to beat Lichess's ease of use), tic-tac-toe pieces or go stones might have been a better fit for this puzzle: to me, at least, chess rooks always bring to mind their distinctive rules of movement, but in this puzzle, you aren't supposed to move the pieces like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes, this is always possible.

Method:

> First we split the problem into one or more sub-problems by condensing chains of rooks: 
>  [image: gfgfg] 
>  This rook chain can be condensed into the following smaller problem: 
>  [image: dsadasa] 
>  We now apply a neat algorithm: 
>  [image: fdgdf] 
>  We first choose an arbitrary pair of rooks and switch them.  This switch, done with either a row or column swap, will affect the positions of exactly two other rooks.  These rooks align to a different diagonal of their bounding rectangle, in orange.  This is simply a convenient intermediate step that allows us to finish switching these two rooks by another row/column swap.  This once again displaces two other rooks, bounded in purple, and we rinse and repeat.
>  Simply repeat this algorithm for each rook chain, and we are done.